# списковая инициализация std::map и std::unordered_map с сужением

Tags: c++

Компилятор разрешает сужающие преобразования для map и unordered_map - это баг компилятора или это разрешено стандартом?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
std::unordered_map<int,int> mm {{44,44}, {33.3, 54}, {222.2,222.2}};
for(auto& [f,s] :mm) {
    std::cout<<f<<" - "<<s<<std::endl;
}

std::map<int,int> m {{44,44}, {33.3, 54}, {222.2,222.2}};
for(auto& [f,s] :m) {
    std::cout<<f<<" - "<<s<<std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Проверил на https://wandbox.org/ - clang10 и gcc10 - для set и unordered_set - компилятор запрещает сужающие преобразования, в то время как с map и unordered_map - другая ситуация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут происходит инициализация с вызовом конструктора

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

который разрешает преобразование.